# How to get the attributes's values of an object in a JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I'm using PDO to store data from a database.
I have an array ($myitems) with a few items where each item has two attributes: id and name.
with PHP I created a list using this array, like you can see in the code below:

**in index.php**

```
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach($myitems as $item): ?>
            <li class="test">
                <form action="edit.php" method="post">
                    <span class="itemlist"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>                    
                </form>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
```

So when the user double clicks in an item of the list, it "transforms" the span into an input text, so the user can update de name of the item. I managed to do this using JQuery where I'm able to get the name of the item because it's being displayed in the *span* tag. This is how I'm getting the name's value and changing the the span to an input text:

**in JS file**

```
 $(".itemlist").dblclick(function (e) {        
            e.stopPropagation();
            var currentEle = $(this);
            var name = $(this).html();
            updateVal(currentEle, name);        
});

function updateVal(currentEle, name) {
    $(document).off('click');
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="liVal"  name="editname" type="text" value="' + name+ '" />');

    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            $(currentEle).html($(".liVal").val());
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine in browser but to update the value of the item in the database I need to submit the form, and this is how I'm doing it:

**also in JS file**

```
$(".liVal").onkeyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.form.submit();
        return false;
     }
});
```

After submit the form, I can get the value of the item's name in the edit.php using the input's attribute name, like this:

**in the edit.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['editname'])){
    $newname= trim($_POST['editname']);     
}
```

But to update an item I also need its id. And here is **THE PROBLEM**, how can I get the id? I really new in PHP and JQuery, I need help with this.

Comment: BTW, thanks for asking a clear question. Surprisingly rare on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the ID as a hidden input field in your form.

```
<ul class="items">
    <?php foreach($myitems as $item): ?>
        <li class="test">
            <form action="edit.php" method="post">
                <!-- ADD ID BELOW -->
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($item['id']); ?>">
                <span class="itemlist"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>                    
            </form>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then when you submit the form, it should have both the ID and your dynamic element.

Comment: I was almost finishing my Answer, but you beat me to it. Not sure about the php syntax, but that's definitely how you do it.

Comment: It is not personally how I would do it, but given the current structure, it is one way of doing it. I personally would use data attributes and AJAX to track all of this and do it dynamically.